# Touchpad no longer working on Ubuntu 18.04 for ASUS zenbook

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I have an ASUS ZenBook running Ubuntu 18.04, and every time I would open up my laptop the touchpad would stop working, so I would open up the terminal and run this:

```
$ sudo rmmod i2c_hid
$ sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

However, recently, even this stopped working. Diagnostics tools tell me that the touchpad isn't even recognized.

```
Gnome Shell Version: 3.28.3
Touchpad Indicator Version: 31
Touchpad(s): No Touchpad detected.
Synclient: Not found or used on your system.
Xinput: Is installed.
Switch Method: XInput
```

So I tried reinstalling some things:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And I have the most recent update for Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is what `xinput` shows:

```
⎡  Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                    id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                         id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: What is the full model of your laptop?

Comment: UX430U ASUS notebook PC

Answer (score 0):

Had problems with my Asus Zenbook UX333F and

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

solved most of them, by installing the latest known kernel on 18.04 (5.2.8 as of today).

Answer (score 0):

Updating to a newer distribution of Ubuntu fixes the problem.

No other solution, even involving the terminal, has permanently fixed the issue for 18.04

Comment: Try my answer... worked for me (installing a newer kernel with `ukuu` had no bad side-effects and fixed all problems, on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: Hi, thanks e2, but as pointed out in the follow up, I am no longer using Ubuntu 18.04, and the issue has been resolved on newer versions of Ubuntu. So you are correct that a newer kernel fixes the problem.